# extract the filename from a path in a Bash

Tags: bash

I have a file which has a lot of links and I need bash script to extract all the names of the files which end with `.pdf` format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the names with

```
grep -o '[^/]*\.pdf' example
```

- `[^/]` matches any single character that is not `/`
- `[^/]*\.pdf` is a (possibly empty) sequence of non-`/` characters, followed by the characters `.pdf` (the backslash before the period makes it literal - otherwise `.` in a regex matches any character)
- the grep `-o` flag outputs each matching portion, one match per line

To de-duplicate the, pipe through `sort` and `uniq`, or `sort -u`

```
grep -o '[^/]*\.pdf' example | sort -u
```

Comment: Please, could you add some details/explanation to the regex expression? I'm interested in understanding how the regex works.

Comment: @LorenzKeel done - please see updated answer

Comment: thanks, it was useful because I forgot that ^ character may have meanings other than "beginning of line"

Answer (score 0):

- Here, `cut` will split the string with space and f1 means first field
- Now `rev` will reverse the string and split the string by '/' using `cut` with `-f1` which wiil give us the last part of the url however in reverse order. So we need to reverse it again!

```
cat filename | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev
```

Comment: it didn't extract the name of the pdf files ?

Comment: also the text file has other links with different format .. in other words how to extract the words after "/" which end with .pdf extansion ?

Answer (score 0):

`basename /usr/bin/poop.txt` 
*would give you* 
poop.txt

i generated a testy.txt file from /usr/bin that contains all of its path/files and edited some of the names to end in .pdf.

so basically testy.txt looks like this: 
/usr/bin/aa-enabled 
/usr/bin/aconnect.pdf 
/usr/bin/alsaucm 
/usr/bin/xargs.pdf 
/usr/bin/xcursogen 
/usr/bin/znew.pdf

You can use basename to extract just the names in the file after grepping pdf.

`basename -a $(grep "\\.pdf" testy.file)`

aconnect.pdf 
xargs.pdf 
znew.pdf

the -a allows the multiple arguments